# Set space between indexes of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, indexing

I am kind off struck in implementation of indexed UITableView. The content display size of tableview in my application is of dimensions 320X250. I am successfully able to display the indexes in tableview as display area is small so half of indexes are displayed by default as "dot symbol".

Any suggestion regarding this would be really helpful.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Think somewhat different & rephrase your question again, could not understand it.

Answer (score 0):

For that,

You have to take UILabel inside the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method.
And assign the label x, y position and width & height. 
So, it will be display properly.

Let me know if you want source code for that.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of iOS. It automatically truncates the indexes when they are too many to display.

Comment: but is there any other way i can display the whole alphabets in small dimensioned tableview?

Comment: @Think Different, I think, No